# What are common server architectures to build a reliable website

Tags: linux, redundancy, architecture, network-design

Sorry, if my question looks too general, but I am looking for an answers to specific problems that I listed below and would appriciate any help.

My website is growing in popularity and I would like to provide a consistant service for my users. Now I have 3 servers and using a cloud storage for static files (like design, javascript and CSS)

[image: server architecture]

Here is the problem I have:

**If webserver falls, everything falls.**

I am using nginx and I was thinking of buying additional servers to scale my web server, but I have about 100 GB of user uploaded text files, user avatars etc. How do I sync all of this between several servers then? Or do I need a separate server as a storage for those files, images? How are those kind of problems solved?

A link to a good book on the topic would be appriciated as well.

Technologies I use: php-fpm, nginx, mysql (percona)

Comment: http://highscalability.com/ - a boatload of mostly useful and entertaining information. And yes, the question is too broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add HAProxy to your stack

2x small servers for HAProxy (with keepalived)

2x (or more!) web servers

for storage I would investigate into Ceph and GlusterFS

Feel free to comment on my reply so we can zero down in the problem.

Comment: I got the idea, thanks for the names! Is HAProxy just a regular machine with HAProxy soft on it?

Comment: Yes, even though there is an appliance as well.